# Excel VBA Dynamic Array spill only complete after end of macro

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic, vlookup

My Dataset contains several transactions in March 2020 in foreign currency. Column A contains the date of each transaction, while column B contains the transaction value in foreign currency (EUR).

I want to calculate the value of each transaction in local currency (being ZAR) in column C using VBA.

Firstly, I obtain all the exchange rates for March 2020  using the STOCKHISTORY function:

```
Dim exchangeRateSummary As Range

Range("I1").Formula2R1C1 = "=STOCKHISTORY(R1C5,R1C6,R1C7)"  'where R1C5 contains EUR/ZAR, R1C6 contains 01-Mar-20, and R1C7 contains 31-Mar-20
Set exchangeRateSummary = Range("I1").CurrentRegion  'save range as variable
```

Then I add a VLookup in column C to determine the local currency value of each transaction, by looping through each row:

```
Dim j As Integer

For j = 2 To 100
cells(j,3).value=cells(j,2).value * Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(j,1),exchangeRateSummary,2,False)
Next j
```

When I run the code, I get the following error: "Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class." When I press End, the spill range of exchange rates (created with the stockhistory function) appears on my Excel sheet. When I run the code again, the VLookup works, and provides the correct local currency values in column C.

The problem is therefore that the VLookup does not work within that same macro, as the spill range created by the stock history function only appears after the macro was executed.

One option is to make these codes separate macros, but I would like to automate this process in one click.

Is there a way I can instruct the macro to first calculate and spill that range, before continuing with the VLookup to that range?

Comment: Please, edit your question and paste the code in discussion. Otherwise, it is difficult to understand what you mean...

Comment: The question could use more details but I think what you are running into is the delay in `STOCKHISTORY` retrieving information and not an issue with spilled arrays.

Comment: From the bit experimenting I have done, the issue seems to be that the value of `STOCKHISTORY` remains #BUSY until all VBA code is finished running.   Someone more knowledgeable than me will need to answer how to force the function to evaluate. I tried DoEvents and a 20 second delay.  Neither of those worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Spill range reference via `#`**

Referring to a spill range can be done via the "#" suffix, i.e. `H2#` if the top cell containing the dynamic STOCKHISTORY formula resides e.g. in `H2`. Couldn't test, but VBA should do this job.

So a possible invented lookup result might be received e.g. via

```
Dim result: result = [VLOOKUP(100,H2#,2,FALSE)]
```

or

```
result = Evaluate("VLookup(" & mySearch & "," & "H2#" & ",2,False")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear and you should try to improve that. That said, with what youve provided, I think you may be able to do something by forcing  calculation in your function where you call the `vlookup`. My guess is that simply wrapping the vlookup might be good enough without having to include the `Workshet.Calculate` call but you'll have to experiment yourself unless you can provide more info in your question.

so something like:
in your worksheet e.g. stock field in `$A$1`, start date in `$A$2` call STOCKHISTORY from B1

```
in Cell B1
=STOCKHISTORY(A1, A2)
```

Then call a function that wraps around vlookup, triggered by a change in `$B$1`, passing your lookup value (say "31-Jan-2020").

```
=vlookup_wrapper("31-Jan-2020", B1)
```

and your wrapper looks something like this

```
Option Explicit

Function vlookup_wrapper(ByVal lookup_val As Variant, ByVal spill_formula) As Variant
  'parameter spill_formula never used, only to trigger this function to be called
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet_with_stockhistory_formula")
  ' force stock history to finish its SPILL
  ws.Calculate

  'Define range from output of STOCKHISTORY spill
  Dim r_in As Range
  Set r_in = ws.Range(ws.Range("B1"), ws.Range("B1").End(xlDown))

  ' Assume want column 2 back
  vlookup_wrapper = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup_val, r_in, 2, False)
  
End Function
```