# Create an array in VBA from the output of a dynamic array function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I just subscribed to ExcelPriceFeed.com and got access to their dynamic array functions.

One of them is EPF.Yahoo.OptionsChain.ExpiryDates

It works when used in an excel cell...
[image: EPF.Yahoo.OptionsChain.ExpiryDates in a cell]

Now I want to call this dynamic array function within a VBA sub and put that list of dates into an array (after which I will loop through the array and create a new tab for each date).
Is this possible?
My code that I've written is...

```
Dim wsUser As Worksheet
Set wsUser = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim sgTicker As String
'sgTicker = InputBox( _
'        "Please input a ticker symbol to extract dates for..." _
'        , "Input a Ticker Symbol" _
'        , "META" _
'        )
sgTicker = "META"
Dim a As Variant
a = wsUser.Evaluate("EPF.Yahoo.OptionsChain.ExpiryDates(""" & sgTicker & """)")
```

After running the code, variable a contains the error 2042.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Otherwise, I'll have to write some code that creates a temporary worksheet and loop through the results in the worksheet.
The cells get a defined name of "A1#".  How would I loop through this range?

Comment: You should ask your vendor if you can access the code via VBA. If your dynamic range in a worksheet starts at `A1`, you can simply copy it to a variant, e.g., `Dim x: x = Range("A1#").Value:   MsgBox x(3, 1)`

Comment: So ok, I've decided to use a temporary worksheet.  The formula needs to placed in cell A1 using .formula2 to stop an implicit intersection operator from being placed in the cell automatically and stopping the spillage.  But still, the formula doesn't execute automatically.  I haven't found a way to do that yet.  It will execute if I manually go to the cell and put the cursor in the formula bar and hit enter.  After that I can process the statement Dim x: x = Range("A1#").Value:   MsgBox x(3, 1)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example but you can try pressing `F9` to calculate your workbook, or in code use `Calculate` or `Range("A1").Dirty`.

Comment: `Calculate` didn't work.  However, `Range("A1").Dirty` worked while stepping through the code.  I was almost so happy!  But when running the macro in full it no longer worked.  Even if I followed `Dirty` with all of `Calculate: Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone : Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")) ` it still didn't work.  Very annoying.

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197626/excel-vba-dynamic-array-spill-only-complete-after-end-of-macro).  The problem wasn't solved back then either.

Comment: Just like the person that posted the problem in the link above, I'm going to divide my script into two and get on with life.  However, the original problem of getting dynamic array formula results into a vba variable/array and the problem of getting a worksheet updated while a script is running remain unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is due to the synchronous nature of VBA/Excel and the asynchronous nature of the function that you are using.

You can try the synchronous version of the function as this will wait for a result to be returned.

Replace the last line of your code with this:

```
a = wsUser.Evaluate("EPF.Yahoo.VBA.OptionsChain.ExpiryDates(""" & sgTicker & """)")
```

The software you are using, Excel Price Feed, has a bunch of synchronous functions that you can use from VBA, more details here: https://www.excelpricefeed.com/userguide/excel-vba-functions-yahoo-finance

I hope this helps.